# At what point does a program become a process virtual machine?

Tags: runtime, virtual-machine, virtualization

At what point does a program who's purpose is to be a runtime become a (process) virtual machine ? What qualifies a program to be called a virtual machine  in contrast to a humble runtime ? Trying to read about real world software does not clarify the distinction.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your notion of "runtime". Typically, this word is used  to highlight that something happens when a program already runs, not before (at e.g. compile time) or after (e.g. when it crashed and got closed) that. A virtual machine is a concept when one program interprets its own data as another program written in certain language to be executed.

Both programs compiled into a native machine language or to some sort of virtual machine language may need a *runtime component* to execute. Examples:

- A program compiled from C++ into machine code needs system libraries that implement standard operations, such as math libraries linked dynamically to it, as well as operating system services, such as file and network input-output
- a Java program compiled into bytecode needs JVM to interpret it, as well as services of memory allocation, garbage collection, thread scheduling etc. from it.

Neither libstdc++ not JVM are present in a program's binary code, they are attached at its *run time*, hence the name.

Comment: That's my question: why do runtime components get called different names like engine, interpreter, runtime library, virtual machine, etc ? They seem to all do very similar things in practice. Is it just marketing or is there a tangible technical difference by the distinction.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_system

Comment: Well, because they do things differently. "Engine" is a generic word meaning nothing in particular; interpreter is a way to execute programs, runtime library is what is a collection of routines loaded at program's run time; virtual machine is a technique of program execution. Read the Wikipedia article you reference and articles it references.

Answer (score 0):

> At what point does a program who's purpose is to be a runtime become a (process) virtual machine?

Any program meant for execution is a runtime. If it is running, that is. If it is only being stored on a disk, it is not at it run time (rather, "wait time" or "non-existence time"). If such a program is written to execute other programs inside itself, it can be considered some sort of a virtual machine.

> What qualifies a program to be called a virtual machine in contrast to a humble runtime?

The word "runtime" is very vague; you should qualify it further, e.g. "runtime library", "runtime analysis", "runtime support" etc. The phrase "virtual machine" is more specific: a "hello world" is typically not a VM, neither is a program to solve a system of linear equations; both of them execute a static algorithm. An interpreter of e.g. Python language is a VM, because what it does is largely defined by the data (another program) it processes, not by the algorithm of the interpreter itself.